# Can't open .NET MAUI project properties

Tags: visual-studio, maui

I created an empty .NET MAUI app project. I'm trying to open the properties, but I get this error:

[image: error message]

> Recoverable
> System.ArgumentException: Expected 8 values for property AndroidRule::AndroidPackageFormat, but got 2.
> Parameter name: values
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.Property.Update(ImmutableArray`1 values)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.Property..ctor(PropertyMetadata metadata, ImmutableArray`1 values, PropertyContext context, ImmutableHashSet`1 varyByDimensions)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.PropertyContextFactoryBase.ToProperty(IUIPropertySnapshot property, Page page, Category category, Int32 order, PropertyContext propertyContext, IPropertyEditorRegistry propertyEditorRegistry)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.g__CreateProperties|14_5(<>c__DisplayClass14_0& )
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.g__ProcessInitialData|14_1(<>c__DisplayClass14_0& )

There were no errors during the installation of VS 2022 Community and its dependencies.

I also opened through JetBrains Rider and everything was fine there, but the functionality in Rider is too limited.

Comment: Did you manually make any changes in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

For this issue, it is more recommended that you post to the Developer Community to get professional support from the VS Technical Support team. The feedback link: [Visual Studio Feedback.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by a complete reinstall of VS.

Comment: Answers (and questions) should be written such that future users can learn from them, too. Please either [edit] this answer to provide details about what was wrong, or consider deleting your question entirely (I think you'll have to delete this answer first).

Answer (score 0):

This issue was .NET8 specific and is fixed now. See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Csproj-Editor-does-not-open-due-to-Andro/10333050.